# Firebase FireAuthErrorCode when email address is empty

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing `FireAuth error` codes for `firebase email` and `password signup`, they all work except in 2 cases. When the `email address` field is empty, `case .errorCodeInvalidEmail` is called. When i type some `letters (no valid email address)`, the default case is called. For the `password field`, it's the other way around. When i type one character the case .`ErrorCodeWeakPassword`" is called. When i leave the field empty, i go to the default case.

**this is my code:**

```
@IBAction func SignInButtonPressed(_ sender: LogInVcButton) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = pwdField.text {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Email User Authenticated with Firebase")
            } else {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                            if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?._code)!) {
                            switch errCode {
                                case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse: self.errorMessage(message: "Email address is already in use")
                                case .errorCodeInvalidEmail: self.errorMessage(message: "Email address is invalid")
                                case .errorCodeWrongPassword: self.errorMessage(message: "Wrong password")
                                case .errorCodeWeakPassword: self.errorMessage(message: "Password needs to be minimum 6 characters")
                                // TODO: A case for if the password field is blank
                                default: print("default")
                                }
                            } else {
                                print("Successfully Authenticated with Firebase")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I don't see which error code would handle the wrong email format or the empty password field in the docs. I can try to handle them my own, but i would think `firebase` would cover these cases ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Anyone can help me out ?

edit: after digging in some deeper i managed to print out the firebase descriptions of the errors.

1. if i pres sign in with emailAddress and password empty:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL})
>
> > case .errorCodeInvalidEmail is called. this is ok

2. When i write an invalid email address and empty password empty i get:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6080000565c0 Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
>       code = 400;
>       errors =     (
>                   {
>               domain = global;
>               message = "MISSING_PASSWORD";
>               reason = invalid;
>           }
>       );
>       message = "MISSING_PASSWORD";
>   }}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
>
> > NOK .errorCodeInternalError: It says missing password, but it should check the email address

3. When i type an invalid email address and one character in the password field i get:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL})
>
> > This seems ok

4. when i type a valid email address and no password:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6080000565c0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
>       code = 400;
>       errors =     (
>                   {
>               domain = global;
>               message = "MISSING_PASSWORD";
>               reason = invalid;
>           }
>       );
>       message = "MISSING_PASSWORD";
>   }}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
>
> > NOK. .errorCodeInternalError

5. when i type a valid email address and one character in the pw field

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17026 "The password must be 6 characters long or more." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The password must be 6 characters long or more., error_name=ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Password should be at least 6 characters})
>
> > .errorCodeWeakPassword is called. This is ok too. and should also be the case on point 5 imo

6. When i type no email and a valid password

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000053ce0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
>       code = 400;
>       errors =     (
>                   {
>               domain = global;
>               message = "MISSING_EMAIL";
>               reason = invalid;
>           }
>       );
>       message = "MISSING_EMAIL";
>   }}}, error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.})
>
> > NOK Internal Error is called. Why not same as in point 1 ?

Comment: There is always an error code. I'd print the `errCode` instead of a hard-coded `"default"` in your default case.

Comment: But i don't want to use the default case. That's too generic

Comment: Agreed that you should not handle authentication errors in a default block. Hence, you'll need to add `case` blocks for all error codes you want to handler. To find out which code you get in what situation, scan the page you linked (there are many more than four you mentioned) or print the error code you get in the default block.

Comment: sure there are many more, but not for my mentioned case. i just don't see them.

Comment: Just `print(error?.code)` anywhere in the completion block and try creating a user with an invalid email. You'll find the code in the console, use it to write a new `case` for invalid emails in your `switch` statement

Comment: it shows  FIRAuthErrorCodeInternalError. I guess it's a firebase thing and i should implement these cases myself ?